# session_id() isn't output anything on PHP

Tags: php

I have two pieces of codes one is the front end website php code that render the front end web pages  and another is the backend api PHP code.  On my front end website code I have **session_start()**;

I have a piece of back end API code that once a user login then I give him or her a **sessionid** by doing `sessionid();`

However, when I use `$sessionid = session_id();` and `echo $sessionid`, nothing's outputted.

```
$user="root";
$password="";
$database="test";
mysql_connect('localhost',$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$username = $first_param;
$username = str_replace( "UserName=", "", $username);
$password = $second_param;
$password = str_replace( "Password=", "", $password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username ='$username' AND password = '$password' ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);

if (debug) {
  echo "<br>";
  echo "--------the num of login is ----" .$num;
}

if ($num <1) {

}
else {
  $sesid=session_id();
  if (debug) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "-----login sessionid is------" .$sesid;
    echo "<br>";
  }
  $query = "UPDATE `user` SET sessionid='$sesid' WHERE username ='$username' AND password = '$password'";
  mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: where is your session_start()?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the code running session_id() is on the same page or included into the page running session_start(). If not, you'll have to run session_start() again to get the session for the new page.

Comment: so you can use as many session_start() as you want without bad effect?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, when you try this, it must work 100%

```
<?php
  session_start(); //This must be called before the session_id();
  $sessionid = session_id();
  echo $sessionid;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is called [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php), note the underscore.

Also your updated code seems to be missing the call to `session_start()`. If this is a separate PHP file from the one `session_start` is otherwise being called in you'll need to call it again at the beginning of this file.